# How to get the height of the li from the top of the screen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a div and inside div, I have ul and li inside it and that li have different classes,  but the classes are in order so I want to find the height of the li:class name, so far I am able to get the height of the div from the top of the screen.

```
<div class="div-class">
  <ul>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
alert($(".div-class").closest('.pdf').offset().top));
```

This code is not working on how to get the height of li with class pdf.

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` traverses *up* the DOM tree. The element you're looking for is a child of the `ul` so you need to go *down*. As such use `find()` instead:

```js
console.log($(".div-class").find('.pdf:first').offset().top);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
  <ul>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="deepesh"></li>
    <li class="pdf">Target element</li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="pdf"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```